# Would this be defined as a hack attempt

Tags: security

In 30 min I received over 300 error emails from my app which stated the below request was coming from the same IP, someone was hitting my server with urls like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com:80/base_local_rules.php?dir=<script>alert('base_local_rules_xss.nasl-1306117559')</script>
http://mywebsite.com/search=<script>alert('XSS')</script>
```

I understand what's happening in the second attempt, can anyone explain the first?

Comment: The first is the same type attack as the second

Comment: Looks like someone is trying to inject script. You should make double sure you are validating all input. Do not trust any input.

Comment: A google search turned up http://www.nessus.org/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=42264 relating to the "base_local_rules_xss" item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a nessus scan of your domain.  Is the source IP by any chance within your service provider's network?  It's entirely possible that they scan all their servers with nessus, in order to detect exploited or otherwise broken machines.

It's also entirely possible this is someone trying to attack your site.

Comment: The ip address I get almost looks like a lan address, trying to find information on where it originated comes up with nothing.